# Dask error reports: calling map_blocks with unmatched dimension error

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Here is the minimal reproducible problem.

> When calling `map_blocks`, **it shows "ValueError: Provided chunks have 3 dims, expected 4 dims".**

Here is my code,

```py
import dask.array as da

x = da.ones((10, 5, 10, 10), chunks=(10, 1, 2, 2))
a = x.map_blocks(f, chunks=(1, 2, 2))
```

where

```py
def f(block):
    return block.max(0)
```

Function `f` will reduce a dim of input data.

And the results show the dimensions are **unmatched**.

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-51c4f85f71a8> in <module>
----> 1 a = x.map_blocks(f, chunks=(1, 2, 2))
      2 a

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py in map_blocks(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   2116     @wraps(map_blocks)
   2117     def map_blocks(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
-> 2118         return map_blocks(func, self, *args, **kwargs)
   2119 
   2120     def map_overlap(self, func, depth, boundary=None, trim=True, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py in map_blocks(func, name, token, dtype, chunks, drop_axis, new_axis, meta, *args, **kwargs)
    617             raise ValueError(
    618                 "Provided chunks have {0} dims, expected {1} "
--> 619                 "dims.".format(len(chunks), len(out_ind))
    620             )
    621         adjust_chunks = dict(zip(out_ind, chunks))

ValueError: Provided chunks have 3 dims, expected 4 dims.
```

Answer (score 0):

See the `map_blocks(drop_axis=...)` keyword

Comment: MRocklin, thanks for your suggestions. It works well.